# amazon ec2 ubuntu server is not reachable

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS Ubuntu EC2 Intance and suddenly it became unresponsive. So I decided to restart server however server is not reachable anymore.

Although in the EC2 console it seems up & running (green); server is not reachable via SSH anymore and the screenshot of the server is as follows:
[image]
[image]

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: I've had cases before where there were problems with the underlying compute node that caused my EC2 instance to become unusable. Only option was to rebuild. Welcome to the cloud.

Comment: Can you restore from a recent snapshot? Snapshots can be taken automatically each night, and it's incremental, so storage costs are reasonable. If you create a new instance you could try to attach the disk of the existing instance to diagnose problems. While AWS does support long lived servers any cloud server should be thought of as ephemeral and a good backup / restore system used.

Comment: I think it is related with a HW error. I had stop / start server multiple times unfortunately couldn't make it up & running again. Fortunately it was a test node only, but I had to create a new instance from scratch since I had no snapshot available for this EC2! :(

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, depending on your IP settings for the instance, that you public IP address has changed when you restarted the instance. Most instances, by default, grab a new IP when restarted.

Check the details of the instance and make sure you are using the correct IP address.

Comment: Stop / start will get a new public IP, but a restart shouldn't. An elastic IP avoids this problem as it's allocated to you for as long as you need it.